# Quadratic Equation positivity

Tags: abstract-algebra, quadratics

$Lemma-4.4.2:$ If $a,b,c$ are real numbers such that $a>0$ and $a\lambda^2+2b\lambda+c\geq0$ for all real number $\lambda$, then $b^2\leq ac$.

**This is from "Topics in Algebra by I.N Herstein"**

$Question:$ Here in this lemma, if we don't assume $a>0$ then it is still valid. Because $a\lambda^2+2b\lambda+c\geq0$ for all $\lambda$, implies $a>0$.So assuming this extra condition is immaterial. Please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

We could also have $a=b=0$, but the conclusion still holds in that case. So the condition is superfluous, but it isn't quite empty because it could possibly not be the case. You could also just as well specify that $a\neq 0$ or $b\neq 0$.

Comment: Here in this lemma, we have assumed quadratic equation so $a\neq 0$.

Comment: @Sumit I don't think that is necessarily assumed in the statement of this lemma automatically. The statements of theorems are independent of the text unless otherwise specified, so if you want $a\neq 0$ you have to say it. It's not the same $a$ as in the exposition.

Answer (score 0):

On the contrary, the condition $a>0$ is necessary. Otherwise, we would not have the quadratic function to be $\ge 0$ identically.

Comment: As long as $a\neq 0$ however, it is implied by the other inequality as the OP says.

Comment: @MattSamuel On the contrary, you can't simultaneously have $a<0,a\lambda^2+2b\lambda+c\ge 0$ for all $\lambda$ real.

Comment: That's not "on the contrary," that's exactly what I'm saying. So the second inequality implies that $a\geq 0$.

Comment: @MattSamuel It's not clear that's what your first comment here means.